# Is it a right sentence? "He was snuffing at my feet like dogs do to me."

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction, metaphors

I have a question about grammar in a sentence.

I want to know how to use "like" in the sentence.

Here is the sentence that I want to ask you:

> He was snuffing at my feet like dogs do to me.

I want to know if this sentence is right. Also, please teach me how to use "like" in sentences as in this kind of situation.

Comment: You should use ***do*** in the subject instead of ***does***. I think your question is closer to a proof-reading request. Is there any difficult part in the dictionary that you don't understand about the conjunction ***like***?

Comment: @Rathony I appreciate your answer. So if I say, "He was snuffing at my feet like a dog does to me," is it a right sentence?

Comment: How about "sniffing"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use both *like dogs do to me* and *a dog does to me*. The reason you  use "do/does" is to avoid repeating the verb *snuff*.

Like is a transitive verb, adjective, noun, adverb, preposition, and ***conjunction***. You need to understand when there is a *clause* that follows it, it should be considered as a *conjunction* that means *as if* or *in the same way that*.

> He was snuffing at my feet ***in the same way that*** dogs do to me.

or

> He was snuffing at my feet like a dog (dogs).

In the above sentence, *like* could be considered as a *preposition*.

Answer (score 2):

your supplementary is also dependant on whether 'he' is a dog. A dog behaving as dogs typically behave with you would be described differently to something else behaving like a dog! "He was snuffling at my feet like a dog" for the latter. "He was snuffling at my feet as dogs do" for the former.

Answer (score 0):

Like would not be correct in this context, with 'as' being a suitable replacement. Like has to be used with the possibility of confusion from its comparative nuance. It can be used to compare behaviours from two different entities as unexpectedly similar. If your foot snuffler were a cat, like would be a good fit here. I'm guessing 'he' is a dog behaving as other dogs do?

Comment: I don't necessarily agree with you. The comparison lies in *snuffing*, not between *a person and a dog*.

Comment: The use of 'he' opening the sentence makes this one confusing without the prior sentance. What is he? A dog behaving like other dogs or some other species snuffling as our subject is used to dogs snuffling? The sentence in the context of more narrative would be clearer on this point.

Comment: You are right, the context is not sufficient, but I don't think the focus is on "what he is". (Anyway, the downvote is not mine).